# ¿Como dar contexto de aplicación a un View dentro de un Fragment?

Tags: android-studio, android-fragment, android-spinner

Estoy tratando de inflar un simple Spinner en un fragment siguiendo las indicaciones de la documentación de Android Developers. A la hora de instanciar el ArrayAdapter me pide un contexto, this no sirve (cargandolo en una activity si me funciona pero en un fragment no) y no me compila la app.

Me pregunto cual será el contexto que habrá que darle a este view para que funcione

Aquí una parte del código

```
spinner?.findViewById<Spinner>(R.id.personsNumberSpinner)
            ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                this,
                R.array.personsNumber_array,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item
            ).also { adapter ->
                adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
                spinner?.adapter = adapter
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si te encuentras dentro de la Activity puedes usar la `Activity` como contexto usando:

`this`

**Pero en tu caso, si te encuentras dentro de un `Fragment` usa como contexto la `Activity` que contiene el `Fragment`** mediante:

```
activity?.applicationContext!!
```

De esta forma:

```
val spinner: Spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner)
// Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
        activity?.applicationContext!!,
        R.array.planets_array,
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item
).also { adapter ->
    // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
    // Apply the adapter to the spinner
    spinner.adapter = adapter
}
```

Comment: funcionó! gracias